# Oracle 12c AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE TRIGGER

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I Have a following trigger, which updates but and rolling back automatically, I'm not finding what is the cause, kindly help.

FYI: updating table UDF_DATA has a foreign key reference to CCEX.CUSTOMER triggering table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_CUSTOMER_PM
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON CCEX.CUSTOMER FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  i_subscriber_id     Number :=3080;
  user_xcep EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( user_xcep, -20001 );
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
  i_syscode ccex.customer.cust_system_code%type;
BEGIN
  IF  :new.cust_account_number like 'TID%' THEN

    i_syscode:=  :new.cust_system_code;
    update udf_data set value = 'Term'
    where subscriber_id = i_subscriber_id
    and cust_system_code = i_syscode
    and entity_id = '1488_OTA'
    and udf_id = '3994_OTA'
    and name = 'Primary Manager';
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  when others then
    raise user_xcep;
END;
/
```

Comment: I feel the foreign key causing the issue, but is there a way to update the other table

Comment: That's fine, can you answer this if you have understand the problem?

Comment: Why are you masking any errors by replacing the exception with an undefined user exception? I would remove that exception handler completely, if I were you.

Comment: An autonomous transaction runs outside the scope of the calling transaction.  That means that in your autonomous transaction, the change to the Customer table is not yet visible.  I assume that is causing the foreign key constraint to fail because the foreign key still references the old version of the data.  Generally, using an autonomous transaction in a trigger to do anything other than logging an attempt to change a value is a mistake.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure what underlying problem you're really trying to solve so I'm not sure what the proper solution would be.

Answer (score 0):

Since the trigger is in `autonomous_transaction` mode, it should close the transaction.

Please add `commit` just before the exception line.